# Problems with an iframe - responsive site - no CSS

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I'm having an issue with an iframe in my site. I made some animated banners through Bannersnack, and I embedded them in my site. Bannersnack provided me with a link to make the images responsive, but this seems to be making the images always appear optimized for a mobile site, even when on desktop.

Here is the site:
http://www.mun.ca/esl/programs/programstest__DRAFT.php

As you can see, the image on bottom scales appropriately, but the animated images in iframes do not. The code for the images is below.

Is there a way to either make the desktop images become the normal size or force the default image size to be scaled on mobile? I'm learning how to do HTML and Bootstrap. I have no idea what CSS is, how it works, or if I can even use it, so a solution that circumvents CSS would be preferable.

Thanks.

Comment: Not using their responsive mebed code, I get this: http://www.mun.ca/esl/programs/programs2__DRAFT.php

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at this page http://www.mun.ca/esl/programs/13_week.php

The first thing I noticed is that the "Admission Requirements" banner has a height and width set, when I removed it the banner acted more responsive but the text inside is very hard to work with because of padding. I almost recommend that you not go with banners because they are hard to make responsive. I've worked on a website in the past that had banners like this.

Comment: Yes. When I did that, I made banner images that were a certain size. Before our site was migrated, everything lined up nicely and I had banner titles instead of text, which is now not possible because the page title must be displayed in text. If I had to make my own static images, I'm sure I could do it fine (and better than I had back then because I know a few more tricks now). However, this animated banner requires an iframe, and I don't know anything about those or why it's misbehaving on me.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, removing the height attribute (100%) in the iframe nearly solved the issue. I'm satisfied with it now.